# Measure time duration between events, partitioned by hours

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands, range-types

I have the following table in *PostgreSQL 9.4*, which persists users log on/off events (log on is `event_type` 1, log off is `event_type` 0).

```
CREATE TABLE user_online_offline_events (
  id serial,
  user_id int4,
  event_type int4,
  created_at timestamp
);
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO user_online_offline_events
       (id, user_id, event_type, created_at)
VALUES (1,  123,     1,         '2015-10-07 12:15:00'),
       (2,  123,     0,         '2015-10-07 12:25:00'),
       (3,  123,     1,         '2015-10-07 12:45:00'),
       (4,  123,     0,         '2015-10-07 13:10:00');
```

I'd like to calculate the number of minutes each user was logged-on *per hour*:

```
| id | user_id |     time | minutes logged on |
+----+---------+----------+-------------------+
|  1 |     123 | 12:00:00 |                30 |
|  2 |     123 | 13:00:00 |                10 |
```

This is my WIP version. It's not really elegant, it still has the hour hard coded in, ignores user_ids and assumes online-offline events are consecutive:

```
select time, sum(minutes) / 60 as minutes from (
  SELECT
    date_trunc('hour', time) as time,
    CASE
    WHEN event_type = 0 AND lag(event_type, 1) OVER w = 1
      THEN
        extract(EPOCH FROM time - lag(time, 1) OVER w)
    WHEN event_type = 0 AND lag(event_type, 1) OVER w ISNULL
      THEN
        extract(EPOCH FROM time - date_trunc('hour', created_at))
    WHEN event_type = 1 AND lead(event_type, 1) OVER w ISNULL
      THEN
        extract(EPOCH FROM date_trunc('hour', time) + INTERVAL '1 hour' - time)
    ELSE 0
    END AS minutes
  FROM user_online_offline_events
  WHERE date_trunc('hour', time) = '2015-10-07 12:00:00'
  WINDOW w AS ( ORDER BY time )
  ORDER BY time
) m group by time;
```

How to do this properly?

Comment: Did you try something?  The harder part is probably finding the corresponding logon-logoff pairs.

Comment: @dezso i've added my WIP version

Comment: It's instrumental to provide an *actual* table definition showing data types and constraints with such a question. The original `CREATE TABLE` script or what you get with `\d user_online_offline_events` in psql. And *always* your version of Postgres, please. *Plus*: define how to handle unmatched logging events: log-on without log-off and vice versa. And times never wrap around?

Comment: Do you want to lump multiple days into one result: I.e.: sum all minutes online between 12:00 and 13:00 for all days in the table etc.? And do you want 24 rows (one fore each hour of the day) for ever user, even without online time? Is there a dedicated user table holding all relevant `user_id` distinctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more sophisticated than I first understood. One way to handle it is with [`generate-series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html), [range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) and associated [functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html):

```
SELECT user_id, hour, sum(upper(min_on) - lower(min_on)) AS minutes_on
FROM  (
   SELECT user_id, hour, u.range * h.range AS min_on
   FROM  (
      SELECT hour, tsrange(hour, hour + interval '1h') AS range
      FROM   generate_series(timestamp '2015-10-07 00:00'  -- defines range of interest
                           , timestamp '2015-10-08 03:00'  -- cut off the rest
                           , interval  '1h') hour
      ) h
   JOIN  (
      SELECT user_id, event_type
           , tsrange(created_at
                   , lead(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at)
                    ) AS range
      FROM   user_online_offline_events
      -- add WHERE conditions to limit selection
      -- careful with cutting off leading "on" / trailing "off" events
      ) u ON u.event_type = 1 AND u.range && h.range
   ) sub
GROUP  BY  user_id, hour
ORDER  BY  user_id, hour;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZEKojlQl) - with extended data
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/10612/1)</sub>

#### Major points

Define the outer time frame in `generate_series()` once. The function generates one row per hour.

Minutes per hours of the day in multiple days are summed up - if the outer time frame spans multiple days.

Hours without any online time are not in the result. If you need that use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`

Using the overlap operator **`&&`** for ranges to identify matching hours and the intersection operator **`*`** to calculate actual overlaps.

Resulting times are given as `interval`. Since multiple days might be summed, the result can be more than one hour and a simple [`EXTRACT()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) would not capture that. You can [extract minutes  as integer number this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23300611/939860):

```
EXTRACT('epoch' FROM sum(upper(min_on) - lower(min_on))) / 60 AS minutes_on
```

Basic timestamp ranges are computed naively with the [window function `lead()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html). This assumes that *every* log-on is followed by a log-off, which typically misses special cases:

- Multiple log-on / log-off events for the same user in a row
- No matching log-on / log-off

You need to define exactly which corner cases can exist and how you want to handle them. There is a solution either way.